# How to calculate square kilometers based on two sets of coordinates

Tags: javascript, coordinates

I'm trying to calculate the square kilometers in an area based on the most south western point and the most north eastern point. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone give me some advice on this matter?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to state the coordinate reference of the coordinate values.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're talking about a quadrilateral with the corners given
by the latitudes/longitudes of the SW and NE corners.  You need then to
specify the edges.  The obvious choice for the W and E edges are
meridian arcs.  For the S and N egdes, reasonable choices are geodesics
(the quadrilateral is a geodesic polygon) and circles of latitude (the
quadrilateral is a rhumb polygon).  The areas in both cases can be
computed by the [Planimeter](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/C++/doc/Planimeter.1.html) utility in my C++ library [GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io).  The area of geodesic
polygons can be computed by the JavaScript package
[geographiclib-geodesic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geographiclib-geodesic).  There's also an [online version of Planimeter](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/Planimeter).  Finally you can derive a
simple formula to this specific rhumb polygon (bounded by lines of latitude or longitude).